# Android studio reverse layout code after reformatting xml layout code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

After reformatting code in layout XML, Android studio 3.5 is reverse whole code. So anyone has a solution for that?

Comment: Try Default code style, go to Settings > Editor > Code style and set it to default

Comment: This problem is also in default code style as well. After updating Android Studio 3.5 this problem occurs.

Comment: I think it's just Rearragening the code, can you try remove "Rearrange code" from the code format?

Comment: Refer this : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129323345

Comment: If you don't have any custom code style for your IDE

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | XML | Arrangement 

Find gear(settings) icon in the top, click it then press "restore defaults".

Answer (score 7):

- Open Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML > Arrangements
- Click Set from... text
- Select Predefined Styles > Android
- Click Apply button